Does approximately null gradient imply approximately global minimum for convex functions?
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ be a non-negative and differentiable convex function which vanishes in a non-empty convex set $\Omega$ - possibly unbounded. Usually, when one approximately minimizes $f$ by quasi-Newton methods, it is obtained a sequence of points $\{x^{k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ so that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\|\nabla f (x^{k})\| = 0.$ However, it does not seem obvious that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f (x^{k}) = 0$. Consequently, there might be a possibility of distancing from the solution set when searching for critical points of convex functions, which seems odd. So here comes the question:

For a non-negative and differentiable convex function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ which vanishes in a non-empty convex set $\Omega$, does $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\|\nabla f (x^{k})\| = 0 \implies \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f (x^{k}) = 0?$$


This question was also asked on the website: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5005166/does-approximately-null-gradient-imply-approximately-global-minimum-for-convex-f

Here is quite late, however, I strongly suspect that it has to do with Theorem 1.10 and Corollary 1.14 of https://www.esaim-proc.org/articles/proc/pdf/2003/01/aze.pdf. These types of error bound rarely are not satisfied far from the solution set, since the gradient of the objective function does not vanish (LICQ is satisfied).

For a convex set with bounded vanishing set, it is only necessary to see that the function is coercive and that $f(x) \leq |\nabla f (x)| \text{dist} (x, \Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is the vanishing set. To see that the function is coercive, just notice that, there is a positive $\delta$ so that $f (x) \geq \delta |x|$ for $|x|$ big enough .

$\newcommand\Om\Omega\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}$The answer is no.
Indeed, for real $k>0$, let
$$G_k:=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\colon x>1,|y|<k\sqrt x\}. $$
For $(x,y)\in G_2$, let
$$f_0(x,y):=y^2/x-1.$$
For all $(x,y)\in\R^2$, let
$$f(x,y):=\max\big(0,\sup_{(u,v)\in G_2\setminus G_1}[f_0(u,v)+(\nabla f_0)(u,v)\cdot(x-u,y-v)]\big)
=\max\Big(0,-1+\sup_{(u,v)\in G_2\setminus G_1}\Big(-\frac{v^2}{u^2},\frac{2 v}{u}\Big)\cdot(x,y)\Big),$$
where $\cdot$ stands for the dot product. The function $f$ is convex, being the pointwise supremum of a family of affine functions. Moreover, $f$ is real valued, because $(-\frac{v^2}{u^2},\frac{2 v}{u})$
is bounded in $(u,v)\in G_2\setminus G_1$.
In fact, for all $(x,y)\in\R^2$,
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
 0 & \text{ if }x\geq h(y),
 \\
 y^2/x-1 & \text{ if }\sqrt{x}<| y| \leq 2 x ,\\
 -4 x+4 y-1 & \text{ if }y\geq \max \left(0,2 x,x+\frac{1}{4}\right) ,\\
 -4 x-4 y-1 & \text{ if }-y\geq \max \left(0,2 x,x+\frac{1}{4}\right),
\end{cases}
\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
where
$$
h(y):=\begin{cases}
 y^2 &\text{ if } | y| \geq 1/2, \\
| y| -1/4 & \text{ if }| y| <1/2.
\end{cases}
$$
In particular, $f=0$ on the nonempty open set $\Om=G_1$. Moreover, it is easy to see that the function $f_0$ is convex on $G_2$. So, $f=f_0$ on $G_2\setminus G_1$ and hence for $y=\frac32\,\sqrt x$ and $x>1$ one has
$$(\nabla f)(x,y)=(\nabla f_0)(x,y)=\Big(-\frac9{4x},\frac3{\sqrt x}\Big)\to(0,0)$$
as $x\to\infty$, whereas $f(x,y)=f_0(x,y)=9/4-1\not\to0$.
Remark 1: The main difficulty here was of course to make $f$ real valued -- a condition having little to do with the essence of the problem.
Remark 2: The function $f$ may be not differentiable at points $(x,y)\in\R^2$ at which at least one of the inequalities in\eqref{1} turns into the equality. However, clearly the differentiability of $f$ has hardly anything to do with the essence of this problem. In particular,
one can smooth $f$ everywhere by (say) convolving it with a mollifier, while retaining the essential properties of $f$ noted above.

For an illustration, here is the graph $\{(x,y,f(x,y))\colon-1\le x\le10,|y|\le4\}$:

